# how can i send switch toggle form through post method

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, ejs

I'm using a ejs template and communicating with app.js through method='post'. how can i send form??

In case of input text this approach below works.

```
<form action="/login" method="POST">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="email">Email</label>
              <input type="email" class="form-control" name="username">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="password">Password</label>
              <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password">
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-dark">Login</button>
</form>
```

but it's not the case with the switch toggle form below. how can i make it work??

```
 <form action="/main" method="POST">
    <div class="custom-control custom-switch">
      <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="sw1" name="toggle2">
      <label class="custom-control-label" for="sw1">On/Off</label>
    </div>
    <div class="custom-control custom-switch">
      <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="sw2" name="toggle1">
      <label class="custom-control-label" for="sw2">on/off</label>
    </div>
    </form>
```

On the server side,

```
app.post("/main",(req,res)=>{
  console.log(req.body.toggle1,req.body.toggle2);
});
```

it should log toggled items, but nothing has been returned.

almost full code for the app.js(serverside)

```
 const app = express();
    const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
    app.get("/main",(req,res)=>{
      res.render("main");
    });
    app.post("/main",(req,res)=>{
      console.log(req.body.toggle1,req.body.toggle2);
    });
```

Comment: I can't understand your server code.please send your full code.

Comment: that's full code for the main form. <form>for the  main.ejs and app.post("/main")for the app.js.

const app = express();
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.get("/main",(req,res)=>{
  res.render("main");
});
app.post("/main",(req,res)=>{
  console.log(req.body.toggle1,req.body.toggle2);
});

Comment: Don't you forget a submit button? ` <button type="submit" ...` ?

Comment: yeah, i'm finding a way to submit without a button.  can't i auto submit the form when the checkbox is checked without clicking a button?